# How should #pragma pack(8) work?

Tags: visual-c++, struct, alignment, pragma-pack

I'm new to structure alignment and packing. I thought I understood it, but I'm finding some results that I did not expect (see below).

My understanding of structure alignment is:

1. Types are generally aligned on memory addresses that are multiples of their size.
2. Padding is added as needed to facilitate proper alignment
3. The end of a structure must be padded out to a multiple of the largest element (to facilitate array access)

The `#pragma pack` directive basically allows overriding the general convention of aligning based on a type's size:

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)
struct SPack8
{
  // Assume short int is 2 bytes, double is 8 bytes, and int is 4 bytes
  short int a;
  double b;
  short int c;
  int d;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

Pseudo struct layout: What I expected:
// note: PADDING IS BRACKETED
0, 1, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] // a occupies address 0, 1
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, // b occupies 8-15 inclusive
16, 17, [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23] // c occupies 16-17 inclusive
24, 25, 26, 27 // d occupies 24-27 inclusive
// Thus far, SPack8 is 28 bytes, but the structure must be a multiple of
// sizeof(double) so we need to add padding to make it 32 bytes
[28, 29, 30, 31]
```

To my surprise, sizeof(SPack8) == 24 on VS 2015 x86. It seems that d is not being aligned on an 8 byte address:

```
offsetof(SPack, a) // 0, as expected
offsetof(SPack, b) // 8, as expected
offsetof(Spack, c) // 16, as expected
offsetof(SPack, d) // 20..what??
```

Can someone please explain what is happening/what I have misunderstood?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is that `#pragma pack` lets you *widen* the struct, it doesn't. `pack` allows you to *pack* the struct more tightly if needed. The `#pragma pack(push, 8)` tells the compiler, that it can **at most** align on 8-byte boundary, but *not more*.

Example:

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct X {
    char a; // 1 byte
    // 1 byte padding
    int b; // 4 bytes, note though that it's aligned on 2 bytes, not 4.
    char c, d, e; // 3 bytes
    //1 byte padding
}; // == 10 bytes, the whole struct is also aligned on 2 bytes, not 4
#pragma pack(pop)

// The same struct without the pragma pack:
struct Y {
    char a; // 1 byte
    // 3 bytes padding
    int b; // 4 bytes
    char c, d, e; // 3 bytes
    // 1 byte padding
};
```

This is what `pack` does, using *less* padding as the compiler would usually use. In your example you tried to align the `int` on 8-byte boundary but since you allowed the compiler to align on *at most* 8 bytes, the 4 byte alignment which the compiler *would like* to use is fine. Your whole struct which is of size 24 also has a size which is a multiple of 8 (your largest member), so no padding needed to fill it up to 32.

You can *forcefully* align your struct

```
__declspec(align(32)) struct Z {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c, d, e;
};
```

or even a member of your struct

```
struct SPack8
{
  // Assume short int is 2 bytes, double is 8 bytes, and int is 4 bytes
  short int a;
  double b;
  short int c;
  __declspec(align(8)) int d;
};
```

on a particular boundary, but I don't see a reason to force a 4-byte type to be aligned on 8 bytes.